# Bytes Upload to the server:

Tags: c#, file-upload

In my application I use below code to upload a file to the server.

```
 response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

where `request.Method is "PUT".`

Is there a way to get the number of bytes uploaded to the server.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Is HttpWebResponse.ContentLength suitable?

Answer (score 0):

why you can't try with [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(VS.80).aspx)

E.g:

```
 WebClient wc = new WebClient();
 byte[] s = wc.UploadFile("string address", "string fileName");
```

Comment: need to have more flexibility with webRequest and webResponse objects instead of WebClient.